# NuGet pack looking for dependency in wrong folder

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nuget-package

I have multiple solutions, that may share packages with each other via NuGet feed (driven by TeamCity, 2018.1.3 (build 58658)). SolutionA exposes few projects to NuGet feed, projects from SolutionB reference some of those packages. Some of projects from SolutionB also should be packed and published to NuGet feed.
For SolutionA packaging and publishing goes perfectly. For SolutionB, packaging of projects, that depend on packages published to NuGet from SolutionA failing because of strange issue. When TeamCity executes NuGet package restore step, packages being downloaded to `packages\Project.From.SolutionA.3.181.181\` folder. Then build step completing successfully, but packaging step failing because of NuGet pack command looks for package in folder `packages\Project.From.SolutionA\3.181.181\`!
Below is build log from pack command (NuGet version is 4.8.1)

```
Missing <TeamCityDir>\buildAgent\work\fbb25b8e9614747\packages\Project.From.SolutionA\3.181.181\Project.From.SolutionA.3.181.181.nupkg
    Error NU5012: Unable to find 'Project.From.SolutionA.3.181.181.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.
    NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find 'Project.From.SolutionA.3.181.181.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.
    at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.AddDependencies(Dictionary`2 packagesAndDependencies)
    at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.ProcessDependencies(PackageBuilder builder)
    at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder(String basePath, NuGetVersion version, String suffix, Boolean buildIfNeeded, PackageBuilder builder)
    at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
    at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage()
    at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
    at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
    at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
    at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
```

The only thing that replaced is real paths and names of projects

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that there aren't more than one solution file (.sln) in your solution?  I was working with an older project that had the main solution file and then some of the sub-projects had their own solution files.  When I ran the build in TeamCity it would fail while trying to find the first nuget package and report the error:

```
Error NU5012: Unable to find 'package.version.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.
```

It took a while but I realized that the projects which failed all had their own solution files which was confusing TeamCity.  Once the files were removed the builds worked.